# How to Convert from String into PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf

Currently I am using this code but its throwing `PrintJobFlavorException`. This is my code help me out fixing this one:

```
public class PJUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
        Writer output = null;
        String text = "printing in pdfPrinting in Java ";
        File file = new File("C:\\CMPSup_AL_.PDF");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
        PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
        job.print(doc, null);
        pjDone.waitForDone();
        is.close();
    }
}
```

and exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Win32PrintJob.java:327)
    at Collections.PrinterJobUtil.main(PrinterJobUtil.java:89)
```

Comment: what makes you think that that text string is a valid pdf document?  (hint, it's not).

Comment: You can't just call a file a PDF, it needs to be an actual PDF-format file. Don't know if that's what the issue is, but it certainly won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your printer may not support text based representation. Have a look at this article [java printing](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2005/jw-0725-print.html?page=1), specially page 5.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out, you can't just create a file called PDF and print it. If you need to generate PDF then you might take a look at [itext](http://itextpdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another option for creating PDF files. Try using [Apache's PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) and take a look at the cookbook. The [HelloWorld](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook/creation.html#HelloWorld) example shows you how to create a simple PDF document like the one you were trying to create in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look on Jasper Reports http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library

Answer (score 0):

Change **DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF** to *DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE*.

E Pavan Varma